# Custom field value link title

Tags: custom-field

I need help with auto detecting the URL's title. The links I am going to use a link to the current website's blog posts.

The code I have right now:

```
<?php
  $custom_fields = get_post_custom($post_id); //Current post id
  $my_custom_field = $custom_fields['Featured-Blog']; //key name
  foreach ( $my_custom_field as $key => $url )
  echo $key."<a href='" .$url. "'>Title</a><br /><br /><br/>";
?>
```

Instead of "Title" I need the code auto detect the URL's title. 
Can someone help?

My functions.php code:

```
        $args = array(

    'labels' =>$labels,

    'public' =>true,

    'publicly_queryable' =>true,

    'show_ui' =>true,

    'query_var' =>true,

    'menu_icon' =>get_bloginfo('template_url').'/images/serviceicon.png',

    'rewrite' =>array('slug' => 'Featured-Blog'),

    'capability_type' =>'post',

    'hierarchical' =>true,

    'menu_position' =>'',

    'supports' =>array('title','editor','thumbnail','custom-fields','excerpt' ),

    'has_archive' =>true

  );
```

Comment: Where does the URL's title come from?

Comment: From the blog post. I am using this custom field for related articles.

Comment: And what data are you storing as the custom field? A post ID? A post permalink? Something else?

Comment: in the value field I add a URL of the blog post I want to use

Comment: Your `functions.php` code appears to be incomplete, but based on what you've posted, you're registering a *custom post type*? If so, then until WordPress 3.7 is released, `url_to_postid()` won't work for you.

Comment: i just posted a part of the function.php code. its a big file. What are my other options?

Comment: and yes to your question about custom post types. I do register them in my function.php file

Answer (score 0):

You would probably make life much easier for yourself if you stored Post `IDs` as your custom meta value, rather than post `URLs`; that said, you can try [back-tracing the Post ID using `url_to_postid()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/url_to_postid), then get the post object from the ID, then get the post title:

```
// Your original code here
$custom_fields = get_post_custom($post_id); //Current post id
$my_custom_field = $custom_fields['Featured-Blog']; //key name

// Your original foreach loop
foreach ( $my_custom_field as $key => $url ) {

    // Fetch the Post ID from the url
    $postid = url_to_postid( $url );

    // Get the post object
    $post_obj = get_post( $postid );

    // Get the post title
    $post_title = $post_obj->post_title;

    // Then construct the link:
    $link = '<a href="' . $url . '">' . $post_title . '</a>';
}
```

### Edit

As stated in the Codex entry for `url_to_postid()`, the function does not currently work properly for custom post types. This behavior is expected to be fixed in WordPress 3.7.

The easiest alternative in the meantime would be to store post `IDs` instead of post `URLs`:

```
// Your original code here
$custom_fields = get_post_custom($post_id); //Current post id
$my_custom_field = $custom_fields['Featured-Blog']; //key name

// Your original foreach loop
foreach ( $my_custom_field as $key => $id ) {

    // Get the post object
    $post_obj = get_post( $id );

    // Get the post title
    $post_title = $post_obj->post_title;

    // Get the post permalink
    $post_permalink = get_permalink( $id );

    // Then construct the link:
    $link = '<a href="' . $post_permalink . '">' . $post_title . '</a>';
}
```

Comment: I replaced the code you suggested and added a posts ID instead of the URL. Nothing is showing up. Do I need to change anything inside function.php ?

Comment: The answer I gave assumes that you're storing the post **URL**, as in your original question. Without seeing your relevant `functions.php` code, there's no way to know if you need to change anything or not.

Comment: Please add all code to your **original question**.

Comment: just did. I look forward to your answer!

Comment: See edited answer, that uses stored post **ID** rather than post **URL**.

Comment: The latest code doesnt work. Nothing is showing

Comment: "*The latest code doesnt work. Nothing is showing*" - please provide appropriate details/information. WPSE is a question/answer site, not a support forum.

Comment: i replaced my code from the php template page with yours and its not working. I just get an empty space in the area where custom field is usually displayed. What other info can I provide?

Comment: Debug the code. Where is the output failing?

Comment: here is teh page: http://beta.leftrightforward.org/breaking-down-barriers-to-international-adoption/
The output for this php code should be under related blog posts. Can you see what else can I change?